# CSS text-align. I don't know whats wrong with my code

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I have just started to code.  But I ran into a error in my css.  The error is that I want the button to align to center but it will not align.

It is probably obvious but I don't know what is wrong.

Please help me. I would love it if you would help.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <h1>Help</h1>
</head>    
<body>
    <br>
    <a class="button" onClick='window.location="view-source:" + window.location.href' target="_blank">View Source</a>
</body>

<style>
    h1 {
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    a[target=_blank] {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .button {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        background-color: #dcdcdc;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "arial";
        font-size: 100%;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

I can't find anything on the web

Comment: Style should go within body.

Comment: Your HTML looks distorted.
<h1> tag must be included inside <body>.
<head> shouldn't contain any rendering elements.

Comment: Thx Brandon Turpy.  It worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you say that you did not find anything on the web, you must not have tried at all.

Read up on the `margin` property and the rest of the HTML and CSS tutorials.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can either wrap the button in a div, or you can put  around it.

**Wrapped in div**
HTML

```
<div class="div_name"><a class="button" onClick='window.location="view-source:" + window.location.href' target="_blank">View Source</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.div_name { text-align: center; }
```

Or

```
<center><a class="button" onClick='window.location="view-source:" + window.location.href' target="_blank">View Source</a></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
margin:auto;
```

that will make it align to the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

you just add

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

text-align attribute specifies inner element,not this element